# CSS transition to bottom-right from center

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have a requirement in which the container is stretching all over the page. when I click on the container, it should become smaller.

This should happen with animation. I tried css transition which is animating the stretched element to top:

- shrinking slowly to the provided dimensions while moving towards top-right

but what I want is

- Shrink in middle and then move to bottom-right of the page by animating.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tyuAk/)

CSS

```
#main {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;    
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#click:hover + #main {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#click {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How should I do this?

Comment: this is a 2 step animation you should look into keyframes http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: Look into CSS Transforms.

Comment: @vico sorry, I forgot to mention that I should also support IE9.

Comment: i guess you can fake the 2 step with jquery add class

Comment: @vico can you provide the solution. I can't use jquery but may be I could transfrom it to javascript by referring. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try combining both `transition` and `animation`. Even you can use only `animation` here:

```
#main {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  top:60px;        
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;    
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#click:hover + #main {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left:-50px;
  margin-top:-25px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-animation: to-bottom-right 0.5s 0.5s forwards;
}
#click {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}


@-webkit-keyframes to-bottom-right {    
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    margin-top:-50px;
  }
}
```

Please test the demo using webkit-based browsers, you can add prefixes yourself for other browsers. Note that the `animation` will run after the transition has been done, so we have to use `animation-delay`.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/tyuAk/11/)

The demo above uses negative margins to center the div, its advantage is well supported but we have to change the negative margins' values when changing the size of the div. Another way is using `translate` transform, this will center the div greatly but it requires browsers to support transform feature. Here is the demo using `translate` instead to center the div **[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/tyuAk/14/)**.

Here is another solution using only `animation`, the transition is just used for animating the color changing.

### [Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/tyuAk/16/).

**UPDATE**: All the demos above work perfectly for browsers supporting ***animation*** feature. However it's a pity that ***IE9*** does not support this feature. I've tried using some workaround and I've found a solution by using multi-transition. The first transition lasts for `0.5s` while the second transition will start after `0.5s`. To animate the div from center to bottom-right corner, you have to use `transition` for the `translate` transform. Here is the code it should be:

```
#main {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  top:60px;        
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;    
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#click:hover + #main {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left:-50px;
  margin-top:-25px;
  background-color: green;   

  -webkit-transform:translate(50vw , 50vh) translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform:translate(50vw , 50vh) translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(50vw , 50vh) translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform:translate(50vw , 50vh) translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease, -ms-transform 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s 0.5s ease;    
}
#click {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tyuAk/19/).

Comment: Thanks, working fine in chrome but not in IE10. I don't mind even if the animation doesn't work but the shrinked container is visible in middle but not in bottom-right in IE10 and below.

Comment: @Mr_Green have you adding prefixes for ***IE***?

Comment: @Mr_Green please try this demo http://jsfiddle.net/tyuAk/11/ I've added prefixes for you, it was edited from the Demo 1.

Comment: It is working in IE10 but not in IE9, the container is visible in middle after shrinking but not in bottom-right. I know animation will not work in IE9 but atleast the container should be visible at bottom-right after animation ending. I hope you get my point.

Comment: @Mr_Green it's because **IE9** does not support `animation` feature, see this http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54999/discussion-between-mr-green-and-king-king).

Comment: I mean your code works perfectly for modern browsers. but for older browsers i.e IE9 and below, the container is ending up at `middle` instead of `bottom-right`. I am expecting the container to end up at bottom-right even `without animation` in older browsers.

Comment: @Mr_Green I've found a work-around for you in the last updated demo, please see if it works (I don't have IE9 to test it).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/4W45N/)

Here's what I changed:

```
#main {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#click:hover + #main {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

I set the position to absolute and the bottom and right properties to 0.  Since the element is not in the document flow any more, I used calc to move set the element 100px smaller than the height.

Comment: Ah, I missed the shrink to the middle part... answer from KingKong is best.

Answer (score 0):

Well i tried

**http://jsfiddle.net/tyuAk/15/**

in jquery tho

```
$("#click").hover(
  function() {
    setTimeout( '$("#main").delay(500).attr("id","newclass");' ,500 );
});

#main {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: red;

}
#newclass {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top:25%;
    background-color: green;

}
#click:hover + #main {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top:25%;
    background-color: green;
    transition-property:width,height,margin;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}


#click {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

#click:hover + #newclass {
    margin-top:0px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```