# center div using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know there are few way to positon a div center vertically and horizontal using css. But for old phone support, I have to do it with js.

http://jsfiddle.net/ncsy9khf/1/

```
div{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
}
```

How do I do the calculation to know what value of my margin top to make the box center center?

Comment: top container location = document hight/2 - container height/2

Comment: Have you searched for it? check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen   or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903556/centering-a-div-vertically-horizontally-using-jquery

Comment: requiredOffset = (screenHeight - divHeight) * 0.5;

Comment: Why don't use `table` ?

Answer (score 2):

This is my favorite way:

```
position:relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

This 5 lines can **vertically *and* horizontally** almost *anything*

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncsy9khf/9/)

---

I learned this method from [this article](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

[Support tables here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

*You can expect 95% of your users have this work perfectly*

---

More browser friendly way:

```
position:relative;
top: 50%;

-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);

left: 50%;

-ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);    
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

## [Friendly Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncsy9khf/8/)

Comment: what if the phone doesn't support transform?

Comment: @JamieAnderson You shouldn't have to worry about tt but, try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312332/fallback-for-css3-transitions

Answer (score 1):

Just use plain CSS:

---

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background: #eee;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FF9800;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="centered"></div>
</div>
```

The parent element *must* have `position:relative;` (*In which you are planning to center the div*)

Also there's no need to add `display:block;` to `div` elements - they are block elements *by default*